# Clickable text in emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I put clickable text in emacs minibuffer?

For example, this code makes clickable text in a text buffer and it works fine for me.

```
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
     (define-key map (kbd "<down-mouse-1>") 
            '(lambda() (interactive) (message-box "it works!")))
     (add-text-properties 1 5 `(keymap, map
                                mouse-face highlight)))
```

However, similar code for minibuffer doesn't work correctly

```
     [...]
     (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window))
       (message "link")
       (add-text-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol) 
                            `(keymap, map
                              mouse-face highlight))))
```

As a result a text is put in a minibuffer without these properties.
I also tried (propertize but result is same.

```
     [...]
     (message (propertize "link" 
                          'mouse-face 'highlight
                          'keymap map)))
```

What's wrong with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `message` writes to the echo area, not the minibuffer.
2. The minibuffer is not active. Even if you use `insert` instead of `message` you will not see the text there.

What is it that you are really trying to do?  What is the context where you want to insert such propertized text in the minibuffer?  The minibuffer is active when, e.g., input is being read.  You can initiate reading and insert the text there when it is active.

Comment: I use propertized text in minibuffer context - `(with-current-buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-window)) [...] )`. So I tried to use `insert` instead of `message` and it shows clickable text in minibuffer. This is what I need. Thank you.